# Throwing out of range exception in C++

Tags: c++, exception

This code works;

```
int at(int index) {
  if(index < 1 || index >= size)
    throw 0;

  return x[index];
}
```

Yet this doesn't

```
int at(int index) {
  if(index < 1 || index >= size)
    throw std::out_of_range;

  return x[index];
}
```

I get the error "expected primary expression before ';'". Now... it surprises me because I know std::out_of_range exists and I have

```
#include <stdexcept>
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two functions?

Comment: oops, copy-paste mistake, now it's ok.

Comment: Why is 0 out of bounds ?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Replace `throw std::out_of_range;` with `throw std::out_of_range ("blah");`.  I.e. you need to create an object, you cannot throw a type.