# Exception class to handle out-of-range errors - C++

Tags: c++

I've created an exception class to handle out-of-range errors in all my member functions in my template class Vector that take an index as a parameter.
I want to know how do I throw an exception of this type if the index is out-of-range? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the exception class:

```
class IndexOutOfRangeException
{
public:
    IndexOutOfRangeException(char* str, int i, int max, int min = 0)
        :message(str),idx(i), last(max), first(min){};
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const IndexOutOfRangeException&);
private:
    char* message;
    int idx;
    int last;
    int first;
};
```

Comment: Why don't you [use an existing class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709719/throwing-out-of-range-exception-in-c) for that purpose? check th link, it can also tell you how to do it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It seems like you don't know how to throw an exception or how to check whether the index is valid, but you show in code that you do. What is your problem? That said, your code has another serious issue: Your exception type doesn't derive from `std::exception`, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear; I did not know how to throw an exception, but the above link helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Why not just use `std::out_of_range`?

```
throw std::out_of_range("Tried to access index 88 of the range [0, 10]");
```

> I want to know how do I throw an exception of this type if the index is out-of-range?

```
throw IndexOutOfRangeException("info", 88, 10, 0);
```