# Replacing SIGABRT with more meaningful description of error in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

When i do a backtrace (bt) in the gdb debugger, it says program recieved signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

In the c++ program I wrote, I just `throw;`

Is there a way to replace the SIGABRT with a more meaningful description of the error?

Something like the `index out of bound error`, or even `index 15 exceeds the bounds of the array with shape (2, 3, 4).`

Comment: Unfortunately, the current state of the science of artificial intelligence in completely insufficient to be able to determine whether an access to an unmapped virtual page is a result of "index out of bounds", or some other error. All that the computer knows is that your code executed a hardware instruction that referenced an invalid memory location. The End.

Comment: I want to name the error within my program, after that, I want gdb to display that error. gdb doesn't have to figure out the error on its own...

Comment: You cannot "name the error within" your program because this "error" is the result of undefined behavior. By the time the "error" occurs, it's too late. Undefined behavior has occured, and the application is in undetermined state. The horse has already left the barn. The correct solution is not to "name the error" in some way, but to fix the code so that the "error" does not occur in the first place.

Comment: ok. then i guess i have to let the program output an error message before it throws up and vomit.

Comment: Would something like `assert( index < 2*3*4);` do?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I *think* the OP wants to detect the error *before* the UB, and then stop with an error.  Actually `fprintf(stderr,.....); exit(EXIT_FAIL)` might be even better.

Comment: I tried assert before. that only work on constants. instead of assert, I made the program print error messages.

Comment: You could pick an exception type such as [std::out_of_range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709719/throwing-out-of-range-exception-in-c), or create your own, and `throw` it, accompanied by a descriptive message. Gdb can catch exceptions using the `catch` command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible to change the signal, but if you want to see a more useful error message in gdb, you could always just throw a specific exception:

```
void do_something(){
    throw std::out_of_range ("This is a very specific message.");
}
```

This will show up in gdb like this:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/pascal/code/exception-test 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  This is a very specific message.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff753c035 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

You can find a list of possible exceptions here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception